# If I configure a remote node.js interpreter do I still need to have node installed locally?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I would like to not have to install any node or npm versions on my host computer, only the IDE, WebStorm.

Can I still run, compile, debug node.js applications if I configure a remote node interpreter in WebStorm to one in Docker or Vagrant ?

Bonus: Would any of this affect ability to run TypeScript?

Comment: as i understand you want to run, compile and etc in docker container?

Comment: Yes @trigun117  I know that Webstorm can connect to a remote interpreter.  But my impression of that is it is used only during execution.  I'm curious if I can have just the IDE (Webstorm) installed on my host computer, and have it use all of the node binaries / dependencies for building (typescript), linting debugging etc from binaries within the Docker container, so that I don't have to pollute my host machine with various versions of node and packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote interpreter can only be used for running/debugging Node.js applications with [**Node.js**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) **Run** configuration. It can't be used for running internal services (linters, Typescript language service, etc.), can't be used to start tests (Mocha, Karma, etc.), can't be used for running NPM. So, the answer is "*Yes*" - you still need to have Node.js installed locally

Comment: That really is too bad :( I love VS code's ability to develop inside Docker containers.  I wish WebStorm would catch up on that.